# run shell script from php

Tags: php, shell, ssh

I am attempting to create a php script that can connect thru ssh to my Qnap TS219 server and run a command on it.

My script so far connects fine to the server but when I run the command I get an error message and I can't figure it out.

exec.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/rapidshare/admin/script.txt /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/rapidshare/admin/script.sh
chmod 755 /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/rapidshare/admin/script.sh
nohup sh /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/rapidshare/admin/script.sh &
exit 0
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/bin/plowdown -o /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/rapidshare /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/rapidshare/admin/down.txt 2>/share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/rapidshare/admin/output.txt
```

the command that I am currently running thru ssh after I submit the form:

```
echo $ssh->exec('sh /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/rapidshare/admin/exec.sh');
```

Right now generates the code below but only after I kill 2 bash processes (the page keeps loading indefinetly and the processor activity is at 100% if I don't kill the 2 bash processes):

```
/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/share/plowshare/lib.sh: line 261: getopt: command not found start download (rapidshare): http://rapidshare.com/files/312885386/Free_Stuff-Your_Internet_eBay_Business_Free_Startup_Resources.rar /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/share/plowshare/lib.sh: line 261: getopt: command not found /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/share/plowshare/lib.sh: line 46: --insecure: command not found Error: failed inside rapidshare_download()
```

This script will be used in my local network, no access from outside, so I am not worry about security, I know the code looks very basic, primitive but I have no experience with php, shell script, so if someone can make any sense on this and help me out  will be greatly appreciated.

Edit1. I also tried the shell_exec command still no joy and if I run the script thru putty works beautifully.

Edit2. I think we are on to something.

I added the code you suggested and I got the following message.

```
sh: /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/share/plowshare: is a directory /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I think at the moment the PATH is usr/bin:/bin:usr/sbin:/sbin and I think it should be /opt/bin /opt/sbin because there are the "executables". Any ideeas?

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Have you tried passthru() or system()?

Comment: Just tried both of them, no luck ... doesn't even generate an error code ... I replaced exec from the command with system and passtrhu (hope that's way I was suppose to do it)... Thanks for you reply, Paul.

C.

Comment: If possible, you should use the Bash builtin `getopts` rather than the external `getopt`. See the section on `getopts` [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035).

Comment: I had a look on that page and to be honest got a bit lost. I'll have a closer look when I get home. Thx, C.

Comment: the error is about missing `getopt` executable. First I would check the contents of `/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/share/plowshare/lib.sh` line 261 as the error says and verify that there's is something related to getopt. Or you can try `echo $ssh->exec('getopt h -h');` and check if problem is non-existing `getopt`.

Comment: getopt is installed, because if I run the script thru putty, works just fine, so I am guessing is a problem with the PATH, like we are discussing below. The linux on the Qnap box is a custom version of the manufacturer so they changed a few things in there. I can oly install software in a certain folder /opt because the system is ready only (I think) and when the server starts there is a file autorun.sh that reenables the link to the /opt/bin where all the "executables" from the software that I install are. Thx, C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this

```
echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
```

Does it list your path correctly? If so then your problem is NOT PHP, if it doesn't list or still gives an error then PHP is your problem and we can continue from there.

From the error you've listed, my first guess would be that PATH isn't set, so lib.sh can't find what it's looking for.

Remember you're logging in with a custom shell (PHP ssh), quite often things aren't set as they should be, so your scripts might not find requirements like paths and variables.

Edit:
Since it's giving /root, we at least know it's going through, why not also set the PATH etc...

```
echo $ssh->exec('PATH=$PATH;/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/share/plowshare; sh /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/rapidshare/admin/exec.sh');
```

Remember you can also use this to see what is and isn't being set.

```
echo $ssh->exec('ECHO $PATH');
```

Comment: /root 

that's the result I get wneh I run the above command.
I was thinking about the same thing regarding the paths to the needed files, but don't know how to fix it ... :( ... hope someone will help me out.

Thx for you reply anyway.
C.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

Following viper_sb logic, I changed the code to:

```
echo $ssh->exec('PATH=$PATH:/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/bin; sh /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/rapidshare/admin/exec.sh');
echo $ssh->exec('echo $PATH');
```

and magic, it worked ... I'll test it further, when I get home, but I think it worked, a file was downloaded in the /Qdownload/rapidshare folder ... hooray.