# Running program from php with exec or shell_exec

Tags: php, command-line, exec

I want to run the following command from PHP (script.php):

```
$output = shell_exec("svn checkout https://IP_REPOSITORY/svn/project/ /home/MY_DOMAIN/domains/MY_DOMAIN.com/public_html/");
```

Nothing is executed and no error is shown if I run script.php file. (File has permissions set to: 777).

What should I do so the script would be properly executed?

Comment: Check the error.log first. It very much depends on the configuration and server setup.

Comment: I can not find anything inside error logs. Maybe I dont know where to look ... I use  Direct admin and I checked for errors in /home/MY_DOMAIN/domains/MY_DOMAIN.com/logs/. Should I search somewhere else?

Comment: When you use php shell PATH isn't always set, perhaps it can't find svn and no (strangely) it won't give an error if it can't find it. Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554693/run-shell-script-from-php it might be helpful.